# Standardisation in PCA: 'scaling' and 'sphering' and the covariance matrices of $\mathbf{X}_{\text{scale}}$ and $\mathbf{X}_{\Sigma}$

Tags: pca, standardization

I'm currently studying **standardisation** in PCA. This primarily involves the generalised standardisation concepts of **scaling** and **sphering**:

> The **scaled** random vector and random sample are
> $$\mathbf{X}_{\text{scale}} = \Sigma_{\text{diag}}^{-1/2} (\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{\mu}) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \mathbb{X}_{\text{scale}} = S_{\text{diag}}^{-1/2} (\mathbb{X} - \overline{\mathbf{X}})$$
> The **sphered* random vector and random sample are
> $$\mathbf{X}_\Sigma = \Sigma^{-1/2} (\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{\mu}) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \mathbb{X}_\Sigma = S^{-1/2} (\mathbb{X} - \overline{\mathbf{X}})$$

This is further illustrated in this image:

> [image]

I am then told the following:

> Let $\mathbf{X} \sim (\mathbf{\mu}, \Sigma)$, and assume that $\Sigma$ has rank $d$. Write $\mathbf{X}_{\text{scale}}$ and $\mathbf{X}_{\Sigma}$ for the scaled and sphered random vectors. These vectors have the following properties:
>
> 1. The expected values of $\mathbf{X}_{\text{scale}}$ and $\mathbf{X}_\Sigma$ are $\mathbf{0}$;
> 2. the covariance matrix of $\mathbf{X}_{\text{scale}}$ is the matrix of correlation coefficient $R$; and
> 3. the covariance matrix of $\mathbf{X}_{\Sigma}$ is the identity matrix $\mathbf{I}$.

I am fine with claim 1., but I'm struggling to see how claims 2. and 3. are true. So how are claims 2. and 3. are true?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ and let $\Sigma$ be Cholesky decomposed into $$\Sigma = \Sigma^{1/2} (\Sigma^{1/2})^\top,$$
where $\Sigma^{1/2}$ is a lower triangular matrix. This is possible since $\Sigma$ is symmetric and positive definite. Then the random variable
$$
Y = \Sigma^{-1/2}  (X - \mu)
$$
is also a Normal random variable, since it is an affine transformation of the normal random variable $X$. Then $Y$ has the expected value
$$\mathbb{E}(Y) =  \Sigma^{-1/2}  (\mathbb{E}(X) - \mu) = \Sigma^{-1/2}  (\mu - \mu) = 0$$
and the covariance is
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(Y) = \Sigma^{-1/2} \mathrm{Cov}(X)(\Sigma^{-1/2})^{\top} = \Sigma^{-1/2} \Sigma^{1/2} (\Sigma^{1/2})^\top(\Sigma^{-1/2})^{\top} = I.
$$
Thus, $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$.

If $Y = D (X - \mu)$ for a diagonal matrix $D$ with the diagonal filled with $\sigma_1,\sigma_2, \dots, $ the covariance of $Y$ is
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(Y) = D\Sigma D = R,
$$
where each element of $R$ is
$$
R_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1, & i=j  \\
 \frac{\mathrm{Cov}(x_i,x_j)}{\sigma_j \sigma_j}, & i \neq j
\end{cases}
$$
Thus $R$ is a "normalized" version of $\Sigma$, as pointed out by [ArnoV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/269787/arnov)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do we know that $\Sigma^{1/2}$ is a lower triangular matrix? It isn’t clear to me why this would be the case.

Comment: Covariance matrices are positive definite by definition, and can thus be [Cholesky factorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition). Intuitively, it can be thought of as the matrix version of the square root.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And how did you get that $\mathrm{Cov}(Y) = \Sigma^{-1/2} \mathrm{Cov}(X)(\Sigma^{-1/2})^{\top}$? I'm not sure what happened for $\text{Cov} (X - \mu)$ (especially to get the $(\Sigma^{-1/2})^{\top}$).

Comment: You can read more on the [Wikipedia page on covariance matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Basic_properties)

Comment: It looks like you used the ${\displaystyle \operatorname {var} (\mathbf {AX} +\mathbf {a} )=\mathbf {A} \,\operatorname {var} (\mathbf {X} )\,\mathbf {A} ^{\rm {T}}}$ property here, right? Can you please explain why this is valid to apply to $Y = \Sigma^{-1/2}  (X - \mu)$? I'm a bit confused about the precise mechanics you used.

Comment: For any constant (i.e. non-random) $m \times n$ matrix $A$ and constant $m \times 1$ vector $a$, one has ${\displaystyle \operatorname {var} (\mathbf {AX} +\mathbf {a} )=\mathbf {A} \,\operatorname {var} (\mathbf {X} )\,\mathbf {A} ^{\rm {T}}}$. $\Sigma^{1/2}$ is a non random matrix of size $n \times n$ and $\mu$ is a non random vector of size $n \times 1$. Then you apply the above formula.

Comment: Hmm, but if $\Sigma^{-1/2}$ is analogous to $\mathbf{A}$ in this case, then don't we actually have $\text{Var}(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} + \mathbf{A} \mathbf{a})$, since matrices are distributive, which would be analogous to $\text{Cov}(\Sigma^{-1/2}\mathbf{X} - \Sigma^{-1/2}\mathbf{\mu})$?

Comment: set $a = - \Sigma^{-1/2}\mu$. Point is that is non random and $\text{Cov}(a) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

By normalising each variable $X_i$ using the marginal means and variances
$$\tilde{X}_i = \dfrac{X_i-\mu_i}{\sigma_i}$$
You make sure that $\mathbb{E}[\tilde{X}_i] = 0$ and $\mathrm{Var}[\tilde{X}_i] = 1$. You however do not fully impact the covariance, as you treat each variable separately. The new covariance changes as
$$\tilde{\Sigma}_{ij} =\mathbb{E}[\tilde{X}_i \tilde{X}_j] = \dfrac{1}{\sigma_i\sigma_j}\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j] = \dfrac{\mathrm{Cov}(X_i,X_j)}{\sigma_i\sigma_j}$$

In order to **whiten** the covariance, you need to combine different dimensions to remove the interaction between $X_i$ and $X_j$. This can be done through a linear transformation $\mathrm{A}x$. The "best" matrix $\mathrm{A}$ can be found by computing the transformed covariance
$$\mathbb{E}\left[(\mathrm{A}x)(\mathrm{A}x)^\mathrm{T}\right] = \mathrm{A}\,\mathbb{E}\left[xx^\mathrm{T}\right]\mathrm{A}^\mathrm{T} = \mathrm{A}\Sigma\mathrm{A}^\mathrm{T} = \mathrm{A}\Sigma^{1/2}\Sigma^{1/2}\mathrm{A}^\mathrm{T}$$
You can see there that if $\Sigma^{1/2}$ is symmetric and invertible, the matrix $\mathrm{A}=\Sigma^{-1/2}$ is the perfect transformation !

If you need to know why the matrix $\Sigma^{1/2}$ exists please open another question, preferably in the math section of the website.

Comment: I don't really see how this answers my question. How is your explanation of the correlation coefficient $\dfrac{\mathrm{Cov}(X_i,X_j)}{\sigma_i\sigma_j}$ relevant to what I'm asking? And where is the explanation for the identity matrix $\mathbf{I}$? A "plain english" explanation would be "here's how it's true for $\mathbf{X}_{\text{scale}}$ ..., and here's how it's true for $\mathbf{X}_{\Sigma}$ ...." It isn't clear what you're addressing in your answer.

Comment: My answer explains both questions 2 and 3. I derive the element $(i,j)$ of the covariance matrix of the scaled variable, and show why sphering the variable is done using this specific transformation'